# Sort an Array based on Redux State, then change the State

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I have a Redux Memory App and in my Redux state I have an Array of 16 Card Objects. I want to randomize the array of Card objects based on a Redux state property called `randomize`

I tried to Sort the Cards from within the reducer and removing the `randomize` property:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
 deck: sort([{name: "Card 1"}, {...}, ...]),
 ...
}
```

But this messes up my onClicks in my 4x4 Field. When I click on a Card, a different one than the one I clicked on is selected. The `sort` algorithm should not be the problem:

```
function sort(cards) {
  const deck = cards;

  let currentIndex = deck.length;
  let temporaryValue;
  let randomIndex;

  while (currentIndex !== 0) {
    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = deck[currentIndex];
    deck[currentIndex] = deck[randomIndex];
    deck[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return deck;
}
```

I would like to sort the cards inside a stateless Component called:

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { select_card } from "../Redux/Actions/actions";
import CardField from "./CardField";

const getRandomizedDeck = (deck, randomize) => {
  if (randomize) {
    return sort(deck);
    // Change randomize to false somewhere
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  deck: getRandomizedDeck(state.deck, state.randomize),
  backside: state.backside
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onClick: (id, name) => {
    dispatch(select_card(id, name));
  }
});

const RandomizedDeck = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(CardField);

export default RandomizedDeck;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that my problem was not with the sorting or dispatching an action but with my reducer checking for the wrong `id` after the cards have been sorted.

To answer my Question I found it better to add an action called `RESET_GAME` and to have this action sort my cards within the reducer like this:

```
    case RESET_GAME: {
      return {
        ...state,
        currentPlayer: 1,
        deck: state.deck
          .map(card => ({ ...card, selected: false, open: false }))
          .sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5),
        playerInfo: state.playerInfo.map(player => ({ ...player, points: 0 }))
      };
    }
```